# CSS flexbox spacing issues with gap property

Tags: css, flexboxgrid

I am having issues with flexbox. When I use the property gap it is making the columns too wide? I am trying to create a simple 3 column row.

I thought that the gap value would not affect the width set? Ie. flex: 0 1 33.33% and gap 2rem would then adjust the width automatically?

Would anyone have any solutions for this issue?

here is the example -
https://codepen.io/CodePlanB1234/pen/WNMypqR

```html
  <div class="row projects--wrapper">
        <div class="card-project--card col-4-12">
          <div class="card-project--image"><img src="/images/bgpic1.jpg" alt="text"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="card-project--card col-4-12">
          <div class="card-project--image"><img src="/images/bgpic1.jpg" alt="text"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="card-project--card col-4-12">
          <div class="card-project--image"><img src="/images/bgpic1.jpg" alt="text"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="card-project--card col-4-12">
          <div class="card-project--image"><img src="/images/bgpic1.jpg" alt="text"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="card-project--card col-4-12">
          <div class="card-project--image"><img src="/images/bgpic1.jpg" alt="text"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="card-project--card col-4-12">
          <div class="card-project--image"><img src="/images/bgpic1.jpg" alt="text"></div>

        </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You can try this `.col-4-12 {width: calc(33.33% - 2rem)}`. It means reduce `2rem gap` from defined width.

Comment: Thanks. I thought when using flexbox it would adjust the width set to incorporate and allow for the gap. Is that not true. 
Ie. I could set the column to 33.33% or 'flex: 0 1 33.33%' and the gap value would be included within that?

Answer (score 1):

gap it take space so in my understanding is to use calc function to reset the column wide by using calc function. In these example the flex that have 4 column for each row which is mean it will have 3 gap column in the same row. As for gap you should set as varible so you can change how much the gap it will be given in gap variable.

---

Here the formula

the formula for width flex item with gap

W = 100%/NC - G/NC*NC-1

NC = number of column on the same row

G = gap range

width = (100% of width row / NC) - (G / NC * NC-1)

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gap {
  --gap: 1em;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.item-four-col {
  width: calc(100% / 4 - calc(var(--gap)/4*3));
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex gap">
  <div class="item-four-col">1</div>
  <div class="item-four-col">2</div>
  <div class="item-four-col">3</div>
  <div class="item-four-col">4</div>
  <div class="item-four-col">5</div>
  <div class="item-four-col">6</div>
</div>
```